# CS50 Pset7 Finance

Tags: cs50

I have question for my CS50 Pset7 finance project. I don't know where to ask this question, so I seek help here. I just finished the register part, however, when I try to test the website, I registered successfully, however, when I try to log in, I got a strange error which I think is because of my way of using hash is not correct. So I got the error `TypeError: invalid method '' for security.py", line 186, in _hash_internal`, and I can see my hash value like `$6$rounds=656000$OiBqI/lX2GqhI8be$G`. I found in the API that the schema support has been removed. I'm wondering how should I use hash method other than `pwd_context.hash(request.form.get("password"))`. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [Asking Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes the code required to reproduce the problem and a **full** stacktrace so we can see what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_password_hash()` to replace `hash()` will work. Don't forget to remove or update the existing entries inside your db since the old hash will cause error.